# Dynamic localization of digits from a number from images in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, localization, mser

I am working on a dynamic digit localization problem from a number in images in Python. What I exactly mean is: if I have an image like this:

[image]

I want to separate all the digits like, 8, 0, 1 like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have tried and explored with MSER, but did not get any far with. And the main problem is, the number can have any number of digits. Another example can be:
[image]

And the number should be separated as 2, 2 like this:

[image]
[image]

Is there any other approach that I can take using open cv or any other packages available in Python?

Comment: If you can isolate the 22 region, then you can unrotated it using minAreaRect. That might help when you want to split the numbers.

Comment: Can you give one code example that might help? And the implementation has to be dynamic for any image and it's orientation. I just gave two examples, but the algorithm has to be generic.

Comment: No, I have no universal solution. You will  have to do your own research. I gave you the simple idea to unrotated such figures. Search google for examples that use cv2.minAreaRect().